# Running two Win XP VMs in VMWare workstation using the same .vmx file

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-workstation

I need to run two XP VMs one as a server and one as a client. I have a Windows XP Professional SP3 x86 English package for the VMWare workstation. I want to run two different XP VMs for the configuration I mentioned. But after opening the .vmx file once, opening the .vmx again only opens the VM I already have opened rather than opening a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clone it, and run them as separate machines. You can't run multiple instances of the same exact machine at the same time.

Comment: I am already doing that. But I am facing issues like capturing network traffic in such a configuration. I am not able to capture any traffice between the two VMs but I am able to capture traffic between any one VM and the native machine. So i was wondering whether the cloning was posing any issues. Any ideas on this.

Comment: `Virtual Machines` are meant to be isolated.